# iOS Size Classes: Restrict to Single ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, size-classes

With Landscape Left and Landscape Right enabled in an app all of the "screens" for the ViewControllers rotate. Is there a way to restrict rotation to a single ViewController in an index of UITabBarViewController in Objective-C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `UITabBarController` will allow not defer calls to the various rotation methods of `UIViewController` to it's children.  It is possible to subclass `UITabBarController` and override these methods with an implementation that calls the method on the currently selected view controller so it can restrict rotation.

Having said that, if you only want a single view controller to be restricted, you run into the issue of the user rotating the screen on a different tab and then selecting the one you want to be locked into a particular orientation.  Since there is no supported way to change orientations arbitrarily (you can only attempt a change to the physical device orientation), there's no good solution to this problem.